# SharePoint 2013 RBS Strange behaviour

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, remote-blob-store

We are using RBS to store the SharePoint files outside the share point content database. This works nice with SP2010. but when we moved to SharePoint 2013 we found that the file has some extra data  and  added to the file in the RBS directory. Is there a way to ask the SharePoint not to add this extra binary data. As our users basically access the RBS through a read-only shared folder on the network and we have done a business that depends on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably referring to shredded storage - in SP2010, there is a single FILESTREAM blob (.rbsblob) for each file version stored on an SP site (e.g. file is stored in the content database, but its content offloaded to RBS). In SP2013, shredded storage can shred a single file version into multiple smaller pieces and pads them with extra bytes, which means that you can't easily access a single file from the RBS itself - and you're not *supposed* to either! What that means is that when you upload a file "document.docx", you don't get a single blob, but multiple smaller blobs (depending on the size and settings) that can't easily be merged together - what you see in RBS are these multiple blobs. The best you can do is to prevent files from getting shreded, but it's a dirty way: [How to disable Shredded Storage in SharePoint 2013?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f2139f21-dee6-48ca-afba-fb4d5c770be7/how-to-disable-shredded-storage-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment) - however, this will only work for newly uploaded files and has impact on storage and performance (shredded storage enables you to e.g. store only deltas of a single document, say if you have 10 document versions that are 50% the same - these 50% will be shared across all versions as shared shreds instead of being stored multiple times as they would in SP2010).

One option that might be useful is to map a [SharePoint site to a network drive](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpmQORJDy-U) and let users work with that instead of RBS directory directly - this way, files will get accessed via RBS without explicitly exposing the blobs (shreds) themselves.

Another option is to download/open a specific RBS-stored file by using `SPFile.OpenBinary()`, which will merge the RBS-stored shreds and return a single (original) file that you can then store elsewhere (e.g. into another shared folder) - this way, you're duplicating files, but that's pretty much how it's supposed to be anyway. For example, this way you can open a file "document.docx" that is visible on an SP site, but stored in RBS as 5 .rbsblob shreds, and save it as "document.docx" elsewhere (outside of SP).

Comment: my next question is how do they generate the padding bytes?

Comment: what I should do to migrate already RBS files that does not have padding from SP2010 ?

Comment: I don't know how the padding bytes are computed ... I guess answering that would require reverse engineering. :)

Migrating files to 2013 depends on your upgrade plan - no single solution. If you wish to reconstruct original files from RBS alone (without the SP content database), this is a hard problem that would, I guess, again require reverse engineering. One option to move blobs from 2010 to 2013 would be to take 2010 blobs and re-upload them to SP2013 as original files so that they get shredded. This is a broad question with many angles to it, depending on what you want to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

RBS storage is internal to SharePoint and you should NOT access its files directly. There are no guarantees that the data will remain in the original format as stated [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748649.aspx):

> Although RBS can be used to store BLOB data externally, accessing or
>   changing those BLOBs is not supported using any tool or product other
>   than SharePoint 2013. All access must occur by using SharePoint 2013
>   only.

Also I'm not aware of any RBS-related configuration for the described behaviour.

Comment: we have rbsblobs generated from SP2010, we need to make them accessible through SP2013. this is a very important thing.